# Local triviality of torsors for relative reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, reductive-groups, principal-bundles

Let $X \to S$ be a relative (smooth proper) curve, and $G \to X$ a reductive group scheme. The following two results are well-known:

1. (Drinfeld-Simpson) For arbitrary $S$, if $G$ is defined over $S$, then any $G$-bundle on $X$ becomes Zariski-locally trivial after an étale base change $S' \to S$.
2. (Steinberg-Borel-Springer -- actually an older result due to Lang, thanks Jason) If $S = \operatorname{Spec} k$ for a field, then writing $F$ for the function field of $X_{\overline{k}}$, we have $H^1(F, G_F) = 0$. It follows that every $G$-bundle on $X$ is Zariski-locally trivial after an étale base change $S' \to S$.

Note the differences: in the first result, $G$ is ``constant" relative to the morphism $X \to S$. In the second result, $G$ is allowed to be a relative group scheme over $X$, but $S$ is restricted to be a field, and a cohomological vanishing argument is being used to descend.

These two results suggest a possible common strengthening:

3. For arbitrary $S$ and $G$ a reductive group scheme over $X$, any $G$-bundle on $X$ becomes Zariski-locally trivial after an étale base change $S' \to S$.

**Is this true?** Does it follow from these two results?

Comment: I believe the result you attribute to Steinberg is due to Serge Lang: Steinberg proved the generalization for all fields $F$ of cohomological dimension one (Serra’s “Conjecture I”).

Comment: Ah, thank you -- I (like many, I suspect), learned about these results from Cohomologie Galoisienne, so didn't know there was an older argument specific to function fields.

Comment: Also you need to be careful with Statement 1. in positive characteristic.  It is certainly true if the reductive group scheme is smooth over $S$.  However, it can fail if the reductive group scheme equals $\mu_p$ in positive characteristic.

Comment: Typo correction: "Serra" --> "Serre".  Sorry about that.

Comment: See the paper "Local triviality for G-torsors" by GIlle, Parimala and Suresh (Math. Ann. 380 (2021), no.1-2, 539–567), in particular Theorem 7.1, for a positive result under some extra conditions.

Comment: @JasonStarr My definition of reductive requires smooth over S, as in Conrad's notes, and even over an algebraically closed field I think that convention is standard. Of course, these results may have a more general setting where one can trivialize after an fppf/fpqc cover.

Comment: That is a very common definition of reductive, but it is not universally accepted, e.g., see the definition of (geometrically) reductive in the following article by Alper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2398

Comment: Probably you know this, but a positive answer to your question is predicted by the Grothendieck-Serre conjecture (this may be proved by now -- check the latest from Ivan Panin, et al.).  In particular, if $S$ is Spec of a field, Nisnevich's proof of the Grothendieck-Serre conjecture over DVRs solves your question.

Comment: @JasonStarr: The Grothendieck-Serre conjecture can only be applied when $S$ is regular.

Comment: @naf What is “4”?  Do you mean regularity of $S$? The stack of $G$-torsors over $X$ should be smooth for reasons of cohomological dimension.  So that would allow to prove, etale locally on $S$, that every family is pulled back from a family where $S$ is regular.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Sorry, "4" was a typo and I agree that one can reduce to the case that $S$ is regular. The Grothendieck--Serre conjecture is known over fields and but not in general. In mixed characteristics this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.08660) of Cesnavicius and Fedorov seems to be the latest result.

Comment: @naf For groups satisfying their hypotheses, the Gille, Parimala, Suresh result is definitely enough to imply my (3) holds on the etale local rings of S (at least for S Noetherian). Is it clear that the Zariski-local triviality descends from the local rings to genuine etale neighborhoods?

Comment: Yes, this is more or less clear: local triviality means that one has local sections and each local section for the strict henselisation will be defined over some etale neighbourhood. There will be finitely many such sections the union of whose domains of definition will cover the special fibre and then you can use properness of $X$ to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me sketch a proof when $G$ is a semisimple group scheme over $X$.  Denote the center of $G$ by $Z_G$, and denote the quotient $G/Z_G$ by $G_{\text{ad}}$.  For every $G_{\text{ad}}$-torsor $E$ over $X$, the  **wonderful compactification** of de Concini and Procesi (with later extensions in joint work with MacPherson) is a smooth, projective scheme $\widehat{E}$ over $X$ with a $G_{\text{ad}}$-action such that $E$ is a $G_{\text{ad}}$-equivariant, dense open subscheme of $\widehat{E}$.  By Grothendieck's "Fondements de la Geometrie Algebrique", there exists an $S$-scheme $\Pi_{\widehat{E}/X/S}$ whose connected components are quasi-projective together with a universal $X$-morphism of the base change, $$X_\Pi:=\Pi_{\widehat{E}/X/S}\times_S X\xrightarrow{\sigma} \widehat{E}.$$ There is a maximal open subscheme $X_\Pi^o$ of $X_\Pi$ on which $\sigma$ is smooth.

The "comb-smoothing" technique of Kollár -- Miyaoka -- Mori, combined with the "rationally connected fibration theorem" of Graber, Harris, de Jong and myself, shows that $X_\Pi^o$ is smooth and surjective over $\widehat{E}$.  Thus, for every quasi-compact open in $S$, there is a quasi-projective open in $X_\Pi^o$ that is smooth and surjective over $S$.  Slicing with hyperplanes produces a closed subscheme $S'$ of $X_\Pi^o$ that us surjective, étale over $S$.  After replacing $S$ by the base change $S'$, there exist sections of $\widehat{E}$ over $S$.  Thus, the original $G_{\text{ad}}$-torsor is Zariski locally trivial.  These trivializations reduce the structure group to $Z_{\text{ad}}$.  Torsors for this finite flat group scheme over $X$ are "rigid".  So after a surjective, étale base change that makes this torsor trivial for one geometric fiber of $X$ over $S$, this torsor is trivialized over $X$ by a surjective, étale base change of $S$.

This proves that after a surjective, étale base change of $S$, you can reduce the structure group of a (smooth) reductive group scheme to a (smooth) multiplicative group scheme.  For these group schemes, I recommend the tool of "flasque tori" to complete the proof.  Of course Harbater, Parimala, Suresh, Hartmann, et al., have their own approach via "patching".  The approaches have different good points and bad points.  It is best to understand both approaches.